# Android BottomSheetBehavior lagging when setState by code

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, bottom-sheet

I have a bottomSheet like this (LinenearLayout ll_main is empty)

```
sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(ll_main);
sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
sheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(bottomSheetCallback);
```

And a button to expand bottomSheet when click

```
if (sheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
      sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
}
```

it work fine but bottomSheet expand lag a bit.
How can i make it smoother?
Thanks.

Comment: Probably profile what is taking so long, that may give you an answer to why its lagging.